install and uninstall RSAT:Server Manager on window 11 pro
I'm having trouble installing RSAT: Server Manager on Windows 11 Pro. When I try to install it, it just says "Couldn't add" and gives me the following error code: 0x80070490. I've tried everything, and I've checked the status of the RSAT installation packages in PowerShell (running as administrator), and they all show as "Staged".enter image description here[error:Could'nt add]
Status:Staged when I install on powershell (running as administrator) 
I've already tried checking Windows Update, running SFC scan, and using DISM to clean and scan for errors. I also tried searching for Server Manager, but there were no results. I even tried using a PowerShell code (with administrator privileges) to uninstall all RSAT packages, but it didn't change the "Staged" status.I hope I can successfully reinstall RSAT: Server Manager.
